# Detect if a number is unique in a mySQL / PHP Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table that has a column like this:

```
ID
-----
0352
5432
4382
3520
30593
3992
295
```

I want to detect if a specific number exists or not.

Note: This table has more than just the ID column.

e.g.

```
$num = 5432
if($num IS IN ID) {
 // code
} else {
 // code
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the numbers to be checked?

Comment: `if a number exists or not` and `Detect if a number is unique` are different tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ID = '5432'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
  // number is in the table
} else {
  // number is not in the table
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a count query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE `ID` = 5432;
```

You can then determine...

- 0 = Does not exist
- 1 = Unique
- >1 = Not unique

---

PDO Example

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE `ID` = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $num);

$num = 5432;
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

switch ($count) {
    case 0 :
        // does not exist
        break;
    case 1 :
        // exists and unique
        break;
    default :
        // exists, not unique
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Phil's answer is spot on if you know the ID in advance. If you want to have a list of all unique ID's from the table in advance (assuming this isn't potentially a memory issue), you can use this query:

```
SELECT `ID`, COUNT(`ID`) AS `IS_UNIQUE` FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `ID` HAVING `IS_UNIQUE` = 1;
```

This will return all IDs that occur exactly once in the table.

Comment: +1 Nice idea. I made this into a further example here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99972/5

Comment: Nice. Because we're dealing with 0 and 1, it can be simplified even more, check your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = {$num}");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    //already exists
} else {
    //does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,
You can always execute a query to the DB like this:

`SELECT COUNT(ID) AS cnt WHERE ID = [your id]`

Then, back in php, after getting the results from query in a $row variable (for example) just siply check

`if ($row['cnt'] > 1)`